# HttpClient NullpointException

Tags: android, json, nullpointerexception, httpclient

my following code works fine when I have an established network connection. I want to get a json string from a site but failed to provide appropriate exception handling when internet is not working or no data connection is available. Could you please help me in handling the exceptions? Because, I have tried a lot but with no success. Thanks in advance!

```
public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, List<NameValuePair> params) {

        try {
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
                HttpResponse httpResponse = null;
                try{
                  httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);}
               catch(NullPointerException e){
                Log.d("nullpoint","check");
                e.printStackTrace();
               }
                int status=httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                if(status==200){
                    HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                    String data=EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
                    json=data.split("<!--")[0];
                    Log.d("Json",json);
                }
        } 
        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
           } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }
            return jObj;
    }
```

Comment: Post the stack trace.

Comment: What Exception are you encountering, and how would you like to handle them? We can't decide for you